# Scrollbar won't scroll to absolute bottom

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll, flowlayoutpanel

I am having a very odd issue using autoscroll in a flowlayoutpanel. There are controls that are programmatically added to the flowlayoutpanel, however, when scrolling to the bottom of the form/flowlayoutpanel, the last control gets cut off. Its almost as if the flowlayoutpanel extends futher and the scrollbar wont scroll down far enough.

Does anyone have any ideas / run into this problem before?

[image]

Comment: Show us the code that reproduces that problem.

Comment: It is likely you are adding the checkbox to a panel inside the `FlowLayoutPanel` rather than adding the control directly to the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: @Loathing I believe I was adding the checkboxes directly to the flowlayoutpanel. In any case, I was required to change the UI design to use different controls. So for now this will no longer be an issue, at least until I inevitably come across something similar in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure all these controls are directly within the `FlowLayoutPanel`?
If they are in a `Panel`, then this `Panel` is not big enough (in `Height`).

Comment: I believe I was adding the checkboxes directly to the flowlayoutpanel. In any case, I was required to change the UI design to use different controls. So for now this will no longer be an issue.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't help.  Answer is to change margins.

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues with FlowLayoutPanel cutting off the bottom of my controls. Here is what helped me for anyone else with a similar problem!

Ensure that the object getting cut off has the proper Margin values.  Something like this will usually work:

```
this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 7, 6, 20);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the **AutoScrollMargin** to an higher height, so you can scroll down to the bottom.